# How to install pybrain?

Tags: python, git, scipy, easy-install, pybrain

I downloaded pybrain using `git`

```
$ git clone git://github.com/pybrain/pybrain.git
```

and when I tried to install,

```
$ python setup.py install
```

it caused error on installing scipy:

```
Running scipy-0.14.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-fxe0wp/scipy-0.14.0/egg-dist-tmp-Kbnkhx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 22, in <module>
    install_requires = ["scipy"],
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 76, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 104, in do_egg_install
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 427, in easy_install
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 478, in install_item
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 519, in process_distribution
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 563, in resolve
    entry = dist.location
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 799, in best_match
    def scan(self, search_path=None):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 811, in obtain
    for dist in find_distributions(item):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 446, in easy_install
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 476, in install_item
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 655, in install_eggs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 930, in build_and_install
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 919, in run_setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 62, in run_setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 105, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 64, in <lambda>
  File "setup.py", line 237, in <module>

  File "setup.py", line 225, in setup_package

ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.core
```

I tried to install another modules, but I met the almost same problem. Can you explain how can I solve it?

Comment: I would probably choose option 1 from https://github.com/pybrain/pybrain/wiki/installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've downloaded it, you can also use pip to do a development install

```
pip install -e /local/path/to/pybrain
```

that way pip might install the dependencies for you.

Some systems have very old pips/setuptools, so you might need to do

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

if the first one fails (I've seen that happen on some systems), try

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

(you'll need write permissions on the required install paths).

edit:  turns out this is not trivial to install... I'm tried the following sequence

```
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
pip install pybrain
```

in a fresh virtualenv on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and scipy complained about a missing BLAS environment variable... I know BLAS is a library for stats or maths, but not much more.

Reading at http://www.scipy.org/install.html it seems that `apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose` might get scipy installed (if you're on the correct Ubuntu versions -- which I'm not..)

Comment: maybe you have a too old version of numpy? `pip install --upgrade numpy`

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using PIP to install modules
Like this:

`pip install pybrain`

But if you cant use that or choose not you, try using @thebjorn's

Hope this helped,

~Bobbeh

P.S, yea I did forget to hit "Post You Answer"

Comment: I have the same output in this case too

Comment: Hmmm, well if it happens with Every Module you have attempted to install, Try to un-install and install python again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe you should install numpy?

```
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

Just install from command line with this command:

```
`pip install pybrain`
```

Comment: please look at [answer]

Answer (score 1):

You can download this script: [ez_setup.py](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py)

and run in shell `$ python ez_setup.py`

also you can use `easy_install` tool:

```
$ easy_install scipy
```